# Constructor and classes in Java

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have one class Account (abstract).
I have one class SavingsAccount (inherits Account).
I have one class CreditAccount (inherints Account).

SavingsAccount and CreditAccount are similar, except CreditAccount has a credit limit (variable limit).

I have the following problems:

1. I need help with how constructor in CreditAccount looks like. How can I add local variable limit to the constructor?
2. Is it better (easier) if I have a variable limit in base class instead, and let SavingsAccount Always set it to be zero, while CreditAccount let the user set the limit?
3. My teacher says since SavingsAccount and CreditAccount are almost the same, @Override are exactly the same, he recommends me to implement those methods in base class (Account). How will the code look like if I do that?

Thank you for your help

class Account:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected double balance = 0;
    protected String accountId;
    protected double interest = 0;

    public Account() {}  

    public Account(double bal, String id, double inte) {   
        if (balance >= 0) {
           balance = bal;
        }
        else {
            balance = 0;
        }
        accountId = id;
        interest = inte;
    }

    public abstract String getAccountId();

    public abstract double getBalance();

    public abstract double getInterest();  
}
```

class SavingsAccount:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {

    public SavingsAccount() {     
        super();
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double bal, String id, double inte) {   
       super(bal, id, inte);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    @Override
    public double getInterest() {
        return interest;
    }

    @Override
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Class CreditAccount:

```
class CreditAccount extends Account {
    private int limit;

    public CreditAccount() {      
        super();
    }

    public CreditAccount(double bal, String id, double inte) { //How can I add local variable limit to this???
       super(bal, id, inte);
    }

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    @Override
    public double getInterest(){
        return interest;
    }

    @Override
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

in main:

```
   System.out.print("Savings or Credit (S/C): ");
   answer = input.next();
   if (null != answer) switch (answer) {
       case "S":
       case "s":{
          System.out.print("Amount to deposit: ");
          double amount = input.nextDouble();
          System.out.print("Interest: ");
          double interest = input.nextDouble();
          SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(amount, accountId, interest);
          newCustomer.addAccount(savingsAccount);
          bank.addCustomer(newCustomer);  
          break;
       }
       case "C":
       case "c":{
          System.out.print("Amount to deposit: ");
          double amount = input.nextDouble();
          System.out.println("Interest: ");
          double interest = input.nextDouble();
          CreditAccount creditAccount = new CreditAccount(amount, accountId, interest); 
          newCustomer.addAccount(creditAccount);
          bank.addCustomer(newCustomer); 
          break;
       }
       default:
          System.out.println("invalid answer");
          break;
       }
```

Comment: The same way you added ctor params to the other classes, I guess. The ctor call will look the same but with an extra parameter.

Comment: thank you. I changed question number 2 since it was too obvious.
See my new question.

Comment: Put everything that is the same in the abstract class; only put what is necessary for the inherited classes in those classes. You may need to read up on OODesign.

Comment: Basically `@Override` is suggesting the class is overriding all or part of the base classes behavior. Considering the behavior doesn't change for those classes, no need to do it. *Anytime* you have repetitious code warrants an investigation.

Comment: Ok, I will put Everything in the base class.
How about my question 1 and 2?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure what you mean because according to your code you know the answer. 2) Easier? Maybe but who cares? Doing that would carry that variable around to all `Accounts`, but not all accounts need it so...no. Also, if you want to direct a comment to another user use @theirName. Most don't hang around on a page awaiting feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions without giving your assignment away...

> 1) I need help with how constructor in CreditAccount looks like. How can I add local variable limit to the constructor?

I suppose you're confused about "*having*" to implement the constructor of the base. Well, that doesn't prevent you from providing one specific to the needs of the sub.

```
public CreditAccount(..., double limit) {
    //call the super from this
    this.limit = limit;
}
```

> Is it better (easier) if I have a variable limit in base class instead, and let SavingsAccount Always set it to be zero, while CreditAccount let the user set the limit?

Better; nope. Easier; that's subjective. Is it easier to set an untold number of sub class' needless variable easier than not including it in the first place?

Easier isn't a factor that overrides good design. The whole point of all this is providing nice little data holders void of clutter. On top of that, it just doesn't seem right; does it; what does your gut say?

> My teacher says since SavingsAccount and CreditAccount are almost the same, @Override are exactly the same, he recommends me to implement those methods in base class (Account). How will the code look like if I do that?

As opposed to the abstract class leaving the methods unimplemented, implement them. Put the simple getters inside the abstract class and *remove* them from the subs. The resulting code would look something like...

```
public CreditAccount ... {
    protected double limit;
    //those constructors you need
    public double getLimit() { ... }
}
```

...for starters.